# OSX Menu bar doesn't appear til opening an application

Tags: macos

When I boot my MBP, the menu bar doesn't appear. When I open Mail.app or Safari, the menu bar appears. I've searched for a bit, and nothing seems to talk about this. Is there a way to fix this?

**UPDATE**

From the Console logs:

```
3/29/12 7:05:10.037 AM com.apple.launchctl.Aqua: load: option requires an argument -- D
3/29/12 7:05:10.037 AM com.apple.launchctl.Aqua: usage: launchctl load [-wF] [-D <user|local|network|system|all>] paths...
3/29/12 7:05:10.100 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.launchctl.Aqua[153]) Exited with code: 1
```

Comment: Does the Dock open automatically when you start up? Does the menu bar appear when opening Finder?

Comment: What happens when you type `killall SystemUIServer` (keep the caps) into Terminal?

Comment: @RandolphWest The dock does, yes. The menu bar does *not* appear when opening finder.

@CoffeeRain I'll try `killall SystemUIServer` when I return home. But wouldn't a reboot solve that as well? I've rebooted several times.

Comment: @CoffeeRain unfortunately, `killall SystemUIServer` didn't do a lot.

Comment: There are some steps to follow on this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1064792?start=0&tstart=0. Start with a Repair Permissions, then remove any third-party plugins you may have recently installed. At least it comes back when you open certain programs, so you can see what's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I had the same problem.

I tried deleting systemuiserver.plist from `~/Library/Preferences` and `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost` and restarted the computer, but it didn’t work.

I then went into the “Desktop & Screen Saver” preferences, deselected and then reselected “Translucent menu bar.” When I rebooted, the menu bar appeared. I rebooted a few more times just to test it and it loaded every time.

Answer (score 0):

In SystemPreferences->General->Appearance: 
check/uncheck "automatically hide and show the menu bar"